# Maximum altitude of a vertical launch taking into account the change in gravity

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, gravity, differentiation, projectile, differential-equations

Say that a body with mass $m$ is launched vertically from the surface of a planet with mass $M$. What is the maximum altitutde the body will reach?

---

My attempt: the equations

$$\frac{d^2}{dt^2}d(t)=a(t)$$ and $$a(t)=G\frac{Mm}{d(t)^2}$$ yield the differential equation

$$d(t)^2\frac{d^2}{dt^2}d(t)=GMm$$

which, if solved, might allow us to find the solutions to $d'(t)=0$ and thus the maximum of the function $d(t)$. However, I can't seem to solve the equation even by means of a [differential equation calculator.](http://ar.symbolab.com/solver/ordinary-differential-equation-calculator/y%5E%7B2%7Dy%27%27%3Dc)

Comment: Your ODE (quite confusing double use of $d$ there!) does have a solution but it can't be made explicit in $t$:  https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%5By%28t%29%5D%5E2+y%27%27%28t%29%3Dc

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hint: In cases where Newton's laws can be used to theoretically solve some problems, but are very difficult in practice, the approach can be made much simpler with a different style of approach, using the notion of energy.

For the problem you have at hand, consider modelling the object and the planet as one system. As there is no significant transfer of energy across the boundary of the system, the total energy of the system (sum of kinetic and *gravitational* potential energy of the system) is conserved and the system can be modelled as an *isolated* system for energy.

You should be able to take it from here. Hope this helps.

Comment: I've always found energy a difficult concept to grapple with. If the acceleration is constant it is easy to show that the expression $mgh+\frac{1}{2}mv^2$ is  constant as well, but how can we show the  expression mantains a constant value even when the acceleration varies? I think I'm going to need a more sophisticated argument than "because energy is conserved".

Comment: In fact, I'm not even sure how to interpret the equation since $g$ varies depending on the height.

Comment: That is actually a separate question in itself. The conservation of energy is a universal law, as long as there are no energy transfers into or out of the system, the energy of the system is constant. Also $mgy$ is _not_ the potential energy of the Earth-object system. The correct equation to use is $U(r) = \frac {-GmM}{r}$, and as you can find out, will simplify to $mgy$ for short altitude changes (where as you point out, the change in gravitational field is negligible at best). Try this and let me know if you have any problems.

Comment: I see. Would the maximum altitude be $\frac{GMm}{mv^2/2-GMm/r}$ where $r$ is the radius of the planet? I'm doubtful since the expression does not seem to depend on $m$.

Comment: Thank you btw. I believe I have found a proof of the formula $W=U+K$ as you describe it in Wikipedia.

Comment: It seems about right, but remember that the "altitude" you've found is actually measured from the centre of the Earth. Altitudes are ususally relative to the _surface_ of the Earth, so you must subtract something (Hopefully you can figure this one out). Also it's completely natural for the result to be independent of $m$. The situation is an idealization,  (notice how we did not consider air drag in the situation and if that was taken into account, the result would be dependent on $m$). This is also why bodies of different masses take the same time to fall down from the same height (ideally)